# dlib matrix<float,0,1> set element

Tags: c++, vector, dlib

What is the equivalent of `std::vector::push_back()` , in `matrix<float,0,1>`
I tried `M(i) = xx,xx` , but the program crash and i get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dlib's matrices have fixed size, they are not auto-extending like STL's vectors

So you can set matrix size and use is:

```
dlib::matrix<double,3,3> m(num_rows, num_cols); // at compile time
dlib::matrix<double> m(num_rows, num_cols); // at construction time
dlib::matrix<double> m; m.set_size(num_rows, num_cols) // at run time
m(1,2) = 1;
```

More information is in [Dlib examples](http://dlib.net/matrix_ex.cpp.html)

And possible reason of segmentation fault is using matrix of unknown size

Comment: Thanks , i didn't set the size of the matrix